# Using try with resources in multithreaded server in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm reading a book "java networking 4th edition" and in the 9th chapter about server sockets while explaining multithreaded server where each client is handled with the single thread it said the following:

> Example 9-3 deliberately does not use try-with-resources for the client sockets accepted by the server
>   socket. This is because the client socket escapes from the try block into a separate thread.
>   If you used try-with-resources, the main thread would close the socket as soon as it got
>   to the end of the while loop, likely before the spawned thread had finished using it.

Here is the Example 9-3

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
public class MultithreadedDaytimeServer {
public final static int PORT = 13;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket connection = server.accept();
                Thread task = new DaytimeThread(connection);
                task.start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't start server");
    }
}
private static class DaytimeThread extends Thread {
    private Socket connection;
    DaytimeThread(Socket connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            Date now = new Date();
            out.write(now.toString() +"\r\n");
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // ignore;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I don't really understand why is this happening, why would main thread want to close the socket from the other thread, is it because socket object was created in the main thread and reference was supplied in thread constructor?

Answer (score 9):

What the book is saying is that they chose to do this

```
try {
    Socket connection = server.accept();
    Thread task = new DaytimeThread(connection);
    task.start();
} catch (IOException ex) {}
```

instead of

```
try(Socket connection = server.accept()) {
    Thread task = new DaytimeThread(connection);
    task.start();
} catch (IOException ex) {}
```

because when use a try-with-resources block, it *closes* whatever you put in the parentheses `try(...)` immediately after it is done. But you do not want this to happen. The `connection` socket is meant to stay open because it is going to be used in the `DaytimeThread` that was started.

Comment: Ohhh, I thought they didn't want try with resources in the run method of thread. So it's okay to use try with resources in run method?

Comment: Yes, it would be totally fine to use it in the run method for the writer.

Answer (score 4):

The main thread doesn't want to close the resource because the spawned thread **executes asynchronously**.

Within the `try`, `task.start()` begins execution of the thread, but it does not wait for it to finish. Therefore, it is possible (even likely) that the main method will reach the end of its `try` before `DaytimeThread.run()` finishes.

If the main method's `try` was a try-with-resources, the connection would be closed at this time. Then, as the `DaytimeThread` continues to do its work in another thread, it would attempt to use that connection after it is closed.

But to answer your actual question:

> why would main thread want to close the socket from the other thread

It's not a socket from another thread. Actually, the **main** method is accepting the socket connection and then giving it to the `DaytimeThread`.

*Typically*, an entity responsible for obtaining a close-able resource should also be responsible for closing it. The simple way to accomplish this is with a try-with-resources. However, this principle cannot be applied with this design because a thread may need the resource after the main thread is done with it.